# Flask-SQLAlchemy: multiple filters through one relation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models, Tags and Photos, that have a many-to-many-relationship like so:

```
tag_identifier = db.Table('tag_identifier',
                          db.Column('photo_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('photo.id')),
                          db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
                         )

class Tag(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Photo(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tag_identifier,
                         backref=db.backref('photos', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

I am trying to query all photos that have multiple specific tags. For example, if I was to query all photos with `<Tag 1>` **and** `<Tag 2>`:

---

`Photo.query.join(Photo.tags).filter(Tag.id==1).all()` would return

`[<Photo 1>, <Photo 2>, <Photo 3>, <Photo 4>]`, and

`Photo.query.join(Photo.tags).filter(Tag.id==2).all()` would return

`[<Photo 1>, <Photo 2>, <Photo 5>, <Photo 6>]`.

---

In this example, what operation would I need to do in order to get the following result:
`[<Photo 1>, <Photo 2>]`

Comment: Did you try, `Photo.query.join(Photo.tags).filter(Tag.id==1).filter(Tag.id==2).all()`.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone Yes, it returns an empty list. Using `and_` does the same.

Comment: Of course, my mistake ;-), given you already have Tag.id==1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
q = (Photo.query
     .filter(Photo.tags.any(Tag.id == 1))
     .filter(Photo.tags.any(Tag.id == 2))
     )
```

Note that you can also check for names:

```
tag1, tag2 = 'tag1', 'tag2'
q = (Photo.query
     .filter(Photo.tags.any(Tag.name == tag1))
     .filter(Photo.tags.any(Tag.name == tag2))
     )
```