# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Filter by upstream foreign key

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Given table structure:

```
themes
theme_id
theme_name

programmes
prog_id
prog_name
theme_id FK

projects
proj_id
proj_title
prog_id FK
```

How do I filter a query based on a foreign key in the upstream table? i.e. return a selection of projects filtering by theme.

If I use:

```
q = Projects.query.filter(
    Programmes.theme_id==1
    )
```

then the SQL produced does not include the join so returns the whole set.

I can work around this by running the programmes query first to get a list of those IDs then filtering projects using `.in_()` but I feel like I am missing something obvious to be able to take advantage of the relationships.

**Workaround**

```
qprg = Programmes.query.filter_by(theme_id=1)
qprj = Projects.query.filter(
Projects.programme_id.in_(
[p.programme_id for p in qprg.all()]
))
```

**Models**

```
class Themes(db.Model):
    theme_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    programmes = db.relationship("Programmes", backref="theme")

class Programmes(db.Model):
    programme_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(2048))
    cluster_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    theme_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('themes.theme_id'))
    projects = db.relationship("Projects", backref="programme")

class Projects(db.Model):
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(2048))
    programme_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('programmes.programme_id'))
```

Comment: Did you try `==` ? Also, can you post your models? You probably want to do a compound filter. Something like what is shown in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306012/flask-sqlalchemy-multiple-filters-through-one-relation)

Comment: So using `==` instead of `=` removes the Keyword error expression but now returns the whole project set

Comment: Is there a way to view the SQL being generated by Alchemy?

Comment: You can print a query object. IE `q = Projects.query.filter(foo); print(q)`

Comment: Ok so the join is missing from the query so I guess the issue in the models

Comment: The relationship I don't think is configured right. I'm far from an expert, but for example, in your `Programmes` class, you define `theme_id` and `theme` -- When I do this, `theme_id` would be the foreign key and the `Theme` class would have a relationship to `Programmes` with a backref of `themes` like what is shown in the Flask-SQLAlchemy [models documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/)